# Repeat Row Number with join

Tags: mysql, sql, row-number

I am trying to get the row number for each increment ID by CUSTOMER_EMAIL.

STAGE_MAGENTO_ORDER TABLE:

| CUSTOMER_EMAIL | INCREMENT_ID | ENTITY_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123@gmail.com | 1232 | 24323 |
| 123@gmail.com | 1258 | 25343 |

STAGE_MAGENTO_ORDER_LINEITEM TABLE:

| PRODUCT_NAME | ORDER_ID |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 24323 |
| Banana | 24323 |
| Pear | 25343 |

Desired Result (Order_NUMBER is the same for each Increment_ID):

```
| CUSTOMER_EMAIL|INCREMENT_ID | ENTITY_ID | PRODUCT_NAME | ORDER_NUMBER |
|---------------|-------------| ----------|--------------| ------------ |
|123@gmail.com  | 1232        |     24323 |Apple         |  1           |
|123@gmail.com  | 1232        |     24323 |Banana        |  1           |
|123@gmail.com  | 1258        |     25343 | Pear         |  2           |
```

Result from trying below (As you can see, the ORDER_NUMBER has increased when it shouldn't):

```
|CUSTOMER_EMAIL|INCREMENT_ID|ENTITY_ID|PRODUCT_NAME|ORDER_NUMBER|
|--------------|------------|---------|------------|------------|
|123@gmail.com | 1232       |   24323 |     Apple  |          1 |
|123@gmail.com | 1232       |   24323 |     Banana |          2 |
|123@gmail.com | 1258       |   25343 |      Pear  |          3 |
```

Code tried:

```
    SELECT 
        o.CUSTOMER_EMAIL
        , O.INCREMENT_ID
        , l.PRODUCT_NAME
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LOWER(o.customer_email) ORDER BY o.CREATED_AT) AS 
    ORDER_NUMBER
        , o.BASE_GRAND_TOTAL - o.BASE_SHIPPING_AMOUNT - o.BASE_TAX_AMOUNT AS NET_SALE
    FROM STAGE_MAGENTO_ORDER o
    INNER JOIN STAGE_MAGENTO_ORDER_LINEITEM l
    ON l.ORDER_ID = o.ENTITY_ID
```

Do I really have to change the to be this? (as I thought it wasn't good to do nested SELECT statements):

```
    SELECT 
        o.CUSTOMER_EMAIL
        , O.INCREMENT_ID
        , l.PRODUCT_NAME
        , o.ORDER_NUMBER
        , o.BASE_GRAND_TOTAL - o.BASE_SHIPPING_AMOUNT - o.BASE_TAX_AMOUNT AS NET_SALE
    FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LOWER(customer_email) ORDER BY CREATED_AT) AS 
    ORDER_NUMBER FROM STAGE_MAGENTO_ORDER) o
    INNER JOIN STAGE_MAGENTO_ORDER_LINEITEM l
    ON l.ORDER_ID = o.ENTITY_ID
```

Comment: Please add your desired outcome

Comment: What is the difference between desired output and 1st table?

Comment: **Pro tip** Don't believe everything you read about query performance. There are lots of silly myths floating around the 'toobz. Write your query to get the result you need, *then* evaluate performance if you must.

Comment: shouldn't your desired result be 1,1,2?

Comment: Hi @P.Salmon. You're right. I have updated the table.

Comment: If sub-queries were inherently bad, so would be views.  SQL is declarative, not imperative; some problems can only be declared using sub-queries.

Comment: Using DENSE_RANK in your first query (instead of ROW_NUMBER) will give the same results as your second query (assuming no two orders for the same email can have the same created time). I would consider your second query more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

Calculating a ROW_NUMBER, RANK or DENSE_RANK in a sub-query is mostly done when you want to filter on it.

In this case a DENSE_RANK would assign the same number for same values.

```
SELECT 
  o.CUSTOMER_EMAIL
, o.INCREMENT_ID
, o.ENTITY_ID
, l.PRODUCT_NAME
, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY LOWER(o.CUSTOMER_EMAIL)
                     ORDER BY o.INCREMENT_ID) AS ORDER_NUMBER
FROM STAGE_MAGENTO_ORDER o
JOIN STAGE_MAGENTO_ORDER_LINEITEM l
  ON l.ORDER_ID = o.ENTITY_ID
```

| CUSTOMER_EMAIL | INCREMENT_ID | ENTITY_ID | PRODUCT_NAME | ORDER_NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123@gmail.com | 1232 | 24323 | Apple | 1 |
| 123@gmail.com | 1232 | 24323 | Banana | 1 |
| 123@gmail.com | 1258 | 25343 | Pear | 2 |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=002f864934aa86242058cf21cbef0329)*

Comment: I think this would just show all row numbers as 1?

Comment: @csharpvsto See updated solution.